# Why do all methods in the Google Analytics tracking code start with an underscore?

Tags: google-analytics

Prefixing variable and method names with an underscore is a common convention for marking things as private. Why does all the methods on the page tracker class in the Google Analytics tracking code (`ga.js`) start with an underscore, even the ones that are clearly public, like `_getTracker` and `_trackPageView`?

Answer (score 5):

Because Google can't be bothered to follow the [Module Pattern](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/) and therefore they don't want accidental collisions in the global namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you have a getTracker() function in your own code, or similar.

In other words, to avoid naming conflicts with the page's javascript code, probably.

@Theo: Didn't realize (ie, not read carefully enough) they were methods. Then maybe to encourage caution or discourage use? Dunno, really.

Comment: Those are methods, there's no possibility of naming conflicts unless I start declaring methods on the page tracker's prototype.

Answer (score 0):

I've always read this like so:

If the property/method is prefixed with an underscore, it is for some "internal" workings.  Therefore if you are about to use/call/alter this property/method, you had better darn well know what you are doing, and or expect it to possibly be renamed/removed in a future release.

Comment: I take it you haven't used Google Analytics? *All* methods on the page tracker object are prefixed with an underscore, even those that explicitly stated as public in the documentation.